# Issue with regex backreference in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am not sure why this is not working. Perhaps I am missing something with Python regex.

Here is my regex and an example string of what I want it to match too:

```
    PHONE_REGEX        = "<(.*)>phone</\1>"
    EXAMPLE            = "<bar>phone</bar>"
```

I tested this match in isolation and it failed. I used an online regex tester and it matched. Am I simply missing something that is particular to Python regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to mark the string as a raw string, due to the `\` in there, by putting an `r` in front of the regex:

```
m = re.match(r"<(.*)>phone</\1>", "<bar>phone</bar>")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is that required anytime a '\' is used? Or just in instances it is used for back-referencing?

Comment: If the first parameter is a variable, just make sure all backslashes are escaped with another backslash in front of it. The following will work as well: `"<(.*)>phone</\\1>"`. It's just that \ has a special meaning in a regex and you'll need to escape it if you literally wish to use a \.